# What is the number of even and odd permutations that satisfies the following condition?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $\phi$ be a permutation of $n$ numbers with $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(2)=2$. It is asked to prove that the number of odd permutations of $n$ numbers that commute with $\phi$ is equal to the number of even permutations of $n$ numbers that commute with $\phi$.

It's been a while since I've worked with the theory of permutations, so really don't know how to approach this. Also, the parity of a permutation is defined as the parity of inversions that the permutation has.

Comment: I've deleted the linear algebra tag and added group-theory.

Comment: It helps to know a little bit of basic group theory to do this. The set of all permutations that commute with $\phi$ forms a group $G$, and the set of even permutations that commute with $\phi$ forms a subgroup $H$. Note that $|H|$ divides $|G|$ by Lagrange's Theorem. Since exactly half of all permutations are even, we have $|G|/|H| \le 2$. So what you are asked to prove is equivalent to showing that $G \ne H$. So you just need to find a single odd permutation that commutes with $\phi$.

Comment: But I don't know group theory, so naturally if the problem can be solved without it, I'd prefer such a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\rho$ commutes with $\phi$, then so does $\rho *\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is a suitable chosen odd permutation. This establishes a bijection between the even and odd commuting permutations.

**Hint:** Use the conditions in the question to determine $\sigma$.